# Codeigniter: Fetch a common column value between same values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following table

```
id    group_id   user_id
1     2          11
2     2          12
3     2          13
4     3          11
5     3          12
6     4          11
```

Now I want the common group IDs Means if

```
I pass user_id (11,12) then result will be group_id (2 and 3)
I pass user_id (11) then result will be group_id (2,3 and 4)
I pass user_id (11,12,13) then result will be group_id (2)
I pass user_id (13,15) then result will be zero group_id (NULL)
```

I am working with CodeIgniter but you can suggestion me in core SQL. It would be good if your answer is in CI model(query) standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct` and `where_in` to get your desire result. Where `array` contain your `user_id`

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('group_id');
$this->db->from('your_table');
$this->db->where_in('user_id',array('11','12');//you can pass here 11,12,13 or 11 or 11,12
```

For And Condition

```
$array = array('user_id' => 11, 'user_id' => 12);

    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('group_id');
    $this->db->from('your_table');
    $this->db->where($array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not working properly. If I passed it (13 and 15) as user_id then it will returns 2, which is wrong. It should be NULL because I want AND operation here. Can you help me

Comment: Try with `$array = array('user_id' => 11, 'user_id' => 12);

$this->db->where($array);`

Comment: Glad to know its working and don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, group_concat(DISTINCT(group_id)) FROM test_temp WHERE user_id IN(11,12)
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to use the NATURAL JOIN of SQL.

For user_id = 11

```
SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 11;
```

For user_id = 11,12

```
SELECT group_id FROM 
    (SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 11) t1 
        NATURAL JOIN 
    (SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 12) t2;
```

For user_id = 11,12,13

```
SELECT group_id FROM 
    (SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 11) t1 
        NATURAL JOIN 
    (SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 12) t2 
        NATURAL JOIN 
    (SELECT group_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 13) t3;
```

Comment: OP asked for Active Records First Read Question Carefully.

Comment: Please explain. I actually tried out this code in MySQL (PhpMyAdmin) and it worked.

Comment: Also this method, will return null, as the OP requested @Bugfixer